# How can I stop a form from being submitted within Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, submit

I have a shipping form with autocomplete for the zipcode and country but I want to stop users from being able to submit a form when their input data isn't valid.

```
function callPickupZipCurl(){

var zipval = $( "#pickupZipCode" ).val();
var type = "zipCountryCode";

//autocomplete
example("input#pickupZipCode").autocomplete({

       minLength:3,
       source: function(request, response) {
           example.ajax({
             url: '<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/search-form/curldata.php', 
             dataType: 'json',
             data: { zipval : zipval , type:type},
             success: function(result) {
                  response(result);                   
             }
           });
       },

        select: function( event, ui ) {
            example( "#pickupZipCode" ).val( ui.item.value );
            example( "#postal_hid_data" ).val( ui.item.id );
            return false;
        }
});             

};


//get zipcode field value
            $( "#pickupZipCode" ).keyup(function( event ) {
                var zipval = $( "#pickupZipCode" ).val();   
                    if (zipval.length > 2) {                
                            callPickupZipCurl();
                    }
            }); 




            //get destination port value
            $( "#destPort" ).keyup(function( event ) {
                var desval = $( "#destPort" ).val();
                    if (desval.length > 2) {                        
                        callDestinationCurl();
                    }                   
            });



//submit code
    $( "#cust_form_submit" ).click(function( event ) {

        if($("input:radio[name='shipment']").is(":checked")) {
            $('#shipmentError').html('');
        }   
        else{
            $('#shipmentError').html('');
            $("#shipmentError").html(' &nbsp;Este campo es obligatorio.');
            return false;
        }

        if($("input:radio[name='load']").is(":checked")) {
            $('#loadError').html('');
        }   
        else{
            $('#loadError').html('');
            $("#loadError").html(' &nbsp;Este campo es obligatorio.');
            return false;
        }

        if($("input:radio[name='load']").is(":checked")) {
            var load_val = $('input:radio[name=load]:checked').val();
                if(load_val=="lcl"){
                        var lcl_weight = $( "#lcl_weight" ).val();
                        var lcl_volume = $( "#lcl_volume" ).val();

                        if(lcl_weight==""){
                            $('#lcl_weightError').html('');
                            $("#lcl_weightError").html('&nbsp; Obligatorio.');
                            $("#lcl_weight").focus();
                            return false;
                        } else { $('#lcl_weightError').html(''); }
                        if(lcl_volume==""){
                            $('#lcl_volumeError').html('');
                            $("#lcl_volumeError").html('&nbsp; Obligatorio.');
                            $("#lcl_volume").focus();
                            return false;
                        } else { $('#lcl_volumeError').html(''); }
                }
        }   


        if($("input:radio[name='pickup']").is(":checked")) {
            $('#pickupError').html('');
        }   
        else{
            $('#pickupError').html('');
            $("#pickupError").html(' &nbsp;Este campo es obligatorio.');
            return false;
        }



        var postalnew = $( "#postal_hid_data" ).val();
        var desnew = $( "#des_hid_data" ).val();
        var postal = $( "#pickupZipCode" ).val();
        var choosePort = $( "#choosePort" ).val();
        var choosePortOther = $( "#choosePortOther" ).val();
        var des = $( "#destPort" ).val();

        var pickup_val = $('input:radio[name=pickup]:checked').val();
        var load_val = $('input:radio[name=load]:checked').val();

            if(pickup_val=="yes"){
                    if(postal==""){
                            $('#zipError').html('');
                            $("#zipError").html('Este campo es obligatorio.');
                            $("#pickupZipCode").focus();
                            return false;
                    } else{ $('#zipError').html(''); }
            }

            if(pickup_val=="no"){

                if(load_val=="lcl"){
                    if(choosePortOther==""){
                            $('#zipError').html('');
                            $("#zipError").html('Este campo es obligatorio.');
                            $("#choosePortOther").focus();
                            return false;
                    } else{ $('#zipError').html(''); }
                }
                else{
                    if(choosePort==""){
                            $('#zipError').html('');
                            $("#zipError").html('Este campo es obligatorio.');
                            $("#choosePort").focus();
                            return false;
                    } else{ $('#zipError').html(''); }
                }

            }


            if(des==""){
                    $('#desError').html('');
                    $("#desError").html('Este campo es obligatorio.');
                    $("#destPort").focus();
                    return false;
            } else{ $('#desError').html(''); }



        var shipment_val = $('input:radio[name=shipment]:checked').val();
        if(load_val=="fcl"){

            if(pickup_val=="no"){
                var postalnew = $( "#choosePort" ).val();
            }   

            if(shipment_val=="export"){
            //www.odesk.com  Export
            window.location = "http://www.icontainers.com/ver-tarifas/FCL/"+postalnew+"/"+desnew;
            }
            if(shipment_val=="import"){
            //www.odesk.com Import
            window.location = "http://www.icontainers.com/ver-tarifas/FCL/"+desnew+"/"+postalnew;   
            }

        }
        if(load_val=="lcl"){
            var lcl_weight = $( "#lcl_weight" ).val();
            var lcl_volume = $( "#lcl_volume" ).val();
            var lcl_volume = lcl_volume.replace(",",".");
                if(pickup_val=="no"){
                    var postalnew = $( "#choosePortOther" ).val();
                }


            if(shipment_val=="export"){
            //www.odesk.com Export
            window.location = "http://www.icontainers.com/ver-tarifas/LCL/"+postalnew+"/"+desnew+"/"+lcl_volume+"/"+lcl_weight;
            }
            if(shipment_val=="import"){
            //www.odesk.com Import
            window.location = "http://www.icontainers.com/ver-tarifas/LCL/"+desnew+"/"+postalnew+"/"+lcl_volume+"/"+lcl_weight;
            }               


        }

        return false;

    });
```

Right now I have it so that, no input within the zip code or country forms gives an alert "Este campo es obligatorio."

But where the code is now, if you input random text into either of the forms and submit it will take you to a 404 page.

Comment: A lot of this code is not related to the problem you're having. Can you trim it down and make it a jsfiddle.net example?

Comment: You can do a javascript validation using regex to make sure it's only numbers, etc.

Comment: Since you are already using jQuery I would look at jQuery validate.

Comment: so how would i go about doing that? sorry, I hired someone  to design and develop for my site. I have a bit of knowledge, but not enough. And for the time being cant afford to hire another programmer.

Comment: @user2662335: you know, some of us went to school for this… many for master’s degrees to. For this, just for this.

Answer (score 0):

Do jQuery or JavaScript browser form/input validation or Php validation through the server. All have pros and cons.

Comment: Using regular expressions.

Comment: ahh, ok. Will go research. Thank you